# Hidden type input value not being passed in Laravel gallery Project

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have created an album. I am trying to upload photos to the album and storing the album_id through the 'hidden' type input. When i check the source code, album_id is shown in 'value' attribute but unfortunately the value is not being passed to the query during form submission.

**My create method of PhotoController which shows the form**

```
public function create($id)
 {   
    $albums = Album::where('id',$id)->first();

    return view('admin.pages.photos',compact('albums', 'id'));
}
```

**Here is the form**.

```
    <div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <a class="btn btn-success" href="/gallery/{{$albums->slug}}">Back to Gallery</a>
    <h4>Upload Photos to <strong>{{$albums-> name}}</strong> Gallery</h4>
    @if (session('status'))
            <div class="alert alert-success">
                {{ session('status') }}
            </div>
        @endif
    <img class="thumbnail" src="/images/gallery/{{$albums->cover_pic}}" alt="{{$albums->name}}">     

</div>
<div class="col-md-8">
<form class="form-horizontal" action="/photo" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-8">Photo Title:</label>
            <input type="text" name="photo_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name of the Photo" value="{{ old('photo_name') }}" >
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-8">Description</label>
            <input type="text" name="desc" class="form-control" placeholder="Write Description" value="{{ old('desc') }}">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-8">Upload Pic</label>
            <input type="file" name="photo" class="form-control" value="{{old('photo')}}" >
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="album_id" value="{{$albums->id}}">
        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success waves-effect waves-light m-r-10">Submit</button>                            
    </form>
```

**and the store method**

```
 public function store(Request $request)
   {
        $this->validate($request, [

        'photo_name'=>'required|min:3',
        'desc'=>'required',
        'photo'=>'required'
        ]);
    $photo = new Photo;
    $photo->album_id = $request->album_id;
    $photo->photo_name = $request->photo_name;
    $str = strtolower($request->photo_name);
    $photo->slug = preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $str);


    if($file=$request->file('photo')){

        $name = time().'.'.$file->getClientOriginalName();

        $file->move('images/gallery', $name);

        $photo['photo'] = $name;

    }
    $photo->desc = $request->desc;

    $photo->save();


    return redirect()->back()->with('status', 'Photo Successfully Added!');
}
```

Comment: Have you done a `dd($request->all())` at the top of your strore method to check if it is actually in the request? There is no reason a hidden field would not be in the post request.

Comment: Hello joe. I don't know what just happened. but the same code seems to work fine automatically. didn't make any changes but it's storing the photos with the album id. Thanks for the instant comment, anyway.

Comment: is album_id in the fillable arrary in your Photo-class?

Comment: yes it was already in fillable array before the problem occured. The problem is solved now though.